# GPIO.getmode() in Python on Raspberry Pi gets different value than on wiki

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am playing around with simple GPIO commands on Raspberry Pi (B version), using built-in Python 3.2 in conjunction with [RPi.GPIO 0.5.11](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO). According to the related [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/), the header pin numbering convention can be set via `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)` or `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` and its status can be read with `GPIO.getmode()`.

The wiki says that the getmode should return either `GPIO.BOARD`, `GPIO.BCM` or `GPIO.UNKNOWN`, however, using `print GPIO.getmode()` I get `10` for BOARD and `11` for BCM.

Why do I get a different-than-wiki result ? Is the wiki outdated or should I render a different command type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting back exactly what the wiki tells you to expect.  Consider:

```
>>> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
>>> GPIO.BOARD
10
>>> GPIO.BCM
11
```

That said, you should always use the named constants (`GPIO.BCM` and `GPIO.BOARD`), never the literal integer values.

Comment: Hm. I am convinced you are right, but still I don't get it: where those numbers come from ? (the 10 and 11) Assuming I only read that wiki without physically testing, how should I know that BOARD corresponds to 10 and BCM corresponds to 11 ? Surely there is a misunderstanding on my part, but don't know where.

Comment: Those are symbols defined in the `RPi.GPIO` module, and the point is that you don't *care* what the actual values are.  The wiki says that `getboard()` returns `GPIO.BCM` or `GPIO.BOARD`.  So you test if the return value `== GPIO.BCM` or `== GPIO.BOARD`.  You don't care if those values are integers, strings, or something else.